# Ejecutar modal Bootstrap con Javascript en una pagina diferente

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap

estuve haciendo varias pruebas y pues, el botón según parece funciona bien ya que usé un console.log(r); y me imprime absolutamente todo el código de la pagina que quiero mostrar así que asumo que está funcionando en parte, ya que la función no funciona ...

Tengo un menú que tiene varios botones y cada botón tiene submenús, entonces la idea es que al presionar click en uno de los sub menús muestre la modal que ya está lista, pero está en otra carpeta.

El código es el siguiente:

Estoy usando varias dependencias pero esta la función está aqui:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/funciones.js"></script>
```

Este es el botón con submenu:

```
<button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            botón1
                        </button>
                        
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="dropdownMenu1">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="carga_gestion()">Subbotón1</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="carga_agenda_gestioncomercial">Subbotón2</a>
                        </div>
```

Y esta es la función que quiero utilizar con ese botón en el archivo anteriormente indicado en las dependencias:

```
function carga_gestion(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"ruta_archivo/sub_boton1.php",
        success:function(r){
            console.log(r);
        }
    });
}
```

Yo creería que si se puede hacer lo que quiero, pero pues únicamente me imprime el contenido en la consola por la linea del ultimo código pero la modal simplemente no se muestra, no se que pueda estar mal y pues he estado revisando desde hace varias horas .

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo creo q primero debes incrustarlo en algun contenedor que ya exista

```
<div id="contenedor"></div>
```

y si tu callback en  (r) es el html q quieres ejecutar, primero haz

```
$("#contenedor").html(r);
```

sin saber como es tu otra parte del codigo que tienes, no podria decirte bien, pero si tu modal se llama mymodal veria si se levanta con:

```
$("#mymodal).modal('show'); dentro del mismo success()
```

Comment: Sep, funcionó correctamente, tuve que agregarle al final un 

dataType:'html' para que funcionara despues del modal('show); pero eso me ayudó bastante.